# How to get jQuery ui range slider value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm making a range slider with jQuery ui and I'm trying to get the value as the slider is being used.

I found some similar examples but all I get is `[object Object]` and not the expected `1`, `2` or `3`.

```js
  $("#range-slider").slider({
    min:1,
    value:2,
    max: 3,
    slide: function( event, ui) {
      $("#text").text($("#range-slider").val(ui.value))
    }
  })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="range-slider"></div>

<p id="text"> </p>
```

What should I change to get the correct result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you're passing `$("#range-slider")` to `$("#text")` which is not the value of the slider but a jQuery object.

So simply pass `ui.value` and it works as what you expected.

```js
$("#range-slider").slider({
    min:1,
    value:2,
    max: 3,
    slide: function( event, ui) {
      $("#text").text(ui.value)
    }
  })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="range-slider"></div>

<p id="text"> </p>
```